# something wrong in cup product on torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let square $ABCD$ represent a torus by identifying $AB$ with $DC$, $BC$ with $AD$.

Let $\alpha$ be a $1$-cocylce which values 1 only on $AB$, $DC$, $AC$.

Then, $$ (\alpha \cup \alpha) ( ABCD)
 =  (\alpha \cup \alpha) (ABC + ACD)
 = 
 \alpha (AB)\alpha (BC) + \alpha (AC)\alpha(CD) = 0 + 1(-1) =-1$$

Here I used the same setting and method as

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414532

But doesn't the general rule of $1$-cocycle require that
$\alpha\cup\alpha=-\alpha\cup\alpha$ and that it equals zero?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2289052/42781?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a well-defined $\Delta$-complex, if you want to identify $AB$ with $DC$, that means $AB$ and $DC$ must have their vertices in the same order.  This means you can't have both $ABC$ and $ACD$ as $2$-simplices, since $ABC$ has $AB$ as an edge (in that order) while $ACD$ has $CD$ as an edge (in that order, which does not match the order of $AB$).  Instead, the two $2$-simplices would need to be $ABC$ and $ADC$, and the cycle representing the whole square would be $ABC-ADC$.  When you calculate $(\alpha\cup\alpha)(ABC-ADC)$ you do get $0$, since now the second term is $\alpha(AD)\alpha(DC)=0$.

(Alternatively, you could be working in singular cohomology so you do have both of the simplices $ABC$ and $ACD$, but then $ABC+ACD$ is not a cycle: its boundary is $AB+CD$ which is not $0$ since $CD$ is not actually equal to $-DC=-AB$.  Note that the cup product is only graded-commutative on the level of cohomology classes, not cochains.  This implies that $\alpha\cup\alpha$ is *cohomologous* to $-\alpha\cup\alpha$ so it must vanish on cycles, but not necessarily on arbitrary chains.)